# Integrate Parse in app with existing push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

A while ago, I released an app with [EasyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) for push notifications, but now I've learned about Parse, and want to switch my app over to it for push notifications. The issue is, most of the users of this app have already enabled push notifications, so

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

is never called, and the allow push notifications alert is never shown, so you can't put the Parse initialization code there. I tried to put it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

but I couldn't find a way to get the device token that Parse needs to be setup.

Is there any way to switch push notification services after the fact, or am I stuck with how I was doing it before?

Comment: I just tested one of my apps and `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` gets called every time the app starts.  The prompt is only shown the first time.  Do you call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` each time the app starts?